# External Url get Image

Tags: php, html, dom

I am using simple html dom for parsing an external url and getting images from it. I can get images from 80% externals urls but some of them gives problems. Example Below.

```
$url = 'http://www.sears.com/shc/s/CountryChooserView?storeId=10153&catalogId=12605';
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
{
   $image_url = $element->src;
   echo $image_url;
   echo "<br />";
}
```

I can get this running at local (23 images) but on server(only 3 images) it is not. code is as i mentioned on top. can anybody help why server is behaving so.

Thanks

Comment: nothing just ignore it...I edited the code

Comment: Is the simple_html_dom & PHP version same at both places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below script

```
$url="http://example.com";

$html = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: @Amere : Still the same problem

Comment: i tried it and i am getting 23 urls both in localhost and in the server. It may be a version issue. i am using php v5.3.5

Comment: Yes You are right. When I uploaded it on other server it started working. Server issue. May be need o talk to server guys for configurations.